# Adding mongodb collection item to discord embed

Tags: javascript, mongodb, discord.js

I want to add my collection docs to an embed using MongoDB ForEach function.

When I want to add a field to an embed inside the foreach, it sends the embed and skips and field adding. When I consoled logged it, it seems that the code sends the message and then add the fields.

```
     const Discord = require("discord.js");
    const mongoDb = require("mongodb").MongoClient;

    let showEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed();
    let proccess = 0;

    module.exports.show = (message, page) => {


            mongoDb.connect('mongodb+srv://admin:31045@robot-xi9jt.gcp.mongodb.net/eco?retryWrites=true', {
                useNewUrlParser: true
            }, function (err, db) {
                if (err) console.log(err);
                let dbo = db.db("eco");
                dbo.collection("items").find({
                    itemPage: page
                }).forEach(function (doc) {
                    console.log(`${doc.itemName} : ${doc.itemPrice} :  ${doc.itemDescription}`)
                    showEmbed.addField(`**${doc.itemName}** | $${doc.itemPrice}`, doc.itemDescription, false);
                })
            });
message.channel.send(showEmbed);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you check the MongoDB documention you'll see that `mongoDb.connect` [returns a Promise](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/MongoClient.html#.connect). Meaning you're code will connect to your database but it will do so in the background. Meanwhile it will continue with the rest of your code, therefor it will send the embed before adding all the fields.

You can easily fix this by moving the `message.channel.send` in to the Promise as well like so:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const mongoDb = require("mongodb").MongoClient;

let showEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed();
let proccess = 0;

module.exports.show = (message, page) => {
  mongoDb.connect('Your connect URL here', { useNewUrlParser: true }, function (err, db) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    let dbo = db.db("eco");

    dbo.collection("items").find({
      itemPage: page
    }).forEach(function (doc) {
      console.log(`${doc.itemName} : ${doc.itemPrice} :  ${doc.itemDescription}`)
      showEmbed.addField(`**${doc.itemName}** | $${doc.itemPrice}`, doc.itemDescription, false);
    });

    message.channel.send(showEmbed);
  });
}
```